# Using an extension from vendor in app/code?

Tags: magento2

I installed https://github.com/yireo/Yireo_Webp2 on a demo shop where composer is available. Now on my customers real shop there is no composer available and wont be in the near future. Yireo Webp requires https://github.com/rosell-dk/webp-convert which came as dependency with Yireo Webp.

Both are now in the vendor folder on the demo shop ... I tried copying the 2 extensions from the demo shops vendor folder to the real shops vendor folder and also modified composer.json and composer.lock accordingly ... did not work. Did I miss something?

Another way I tried is to copy the Yireo Extension to `app/code`, which makes it appear in admin, but as soon as I open a category page, it complains about a missing class which comes with https://github.com/rosell-dk/webp-convert. So, I tried copying https://github.com/rosell-dk/webp-convert to `app/code` as well, but I do not know how, is this even possible?

Thanks for any help on how to solve this :-).

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1**- Download the zip file from link- [module](https://github.com/rosell-dk/webp-convert) . And unzip the file.

**Step 2**- Create another directory called app/code/your_vendor_name/WebPConvert/. WebPConvert is the module's internal identifier. You can find it in the "composer.json" file in the extension ZIP file you downloaded, look at the node "psr-4".

This is what you call the directory, and then you put the contents of the extension ZIP file in there.

**Step 3**- Run magento deployment commands and test it.

Comment: Thanks, so I place the content in app/code/Rosell/WebPConvert for example? Do I have to enable the extension afterwards like this `php bin/magento module:enable Rosell_WebPConvert`?

Comment: The structure is not the same as for a usual app/code extension, no registration.php file, but a src folder and so on. Are you sure it would work this way?

Comment: I think it should work. Did you try this yet?

Comment: Yes I did, did not work ... the rosell-dk is more of a library I guess, not an extension.